# Discord bot is not reading messages (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'am using discord.js v14.7.1, here is my code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GuildModeration", "GuildMessages", "GuildMessageTyping", "GuildMembers", "MessageContent"] });
client.once('ready', () => {

console.log("odpalony");
client.user.setActivity("BOT WERSJA BETA");

});
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
console.log(message.content);
});

client.login('*****');
```

I don't get any errors and the console is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `messageCreate` event won't trigger without the `"Guilds"` intent, so you'll need to add it.

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    'Guilds',
    'GuildMessages',
    'GuildMessageTyping',
    'GuildMembers',
    'GuildModeration',
    'MessageContent',
  ],
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i just added Guilds and it works with guild moderation intent, so I think that it exists

Comment: You're absolutely right, I've fixed that. It seems `GuildBans` is deprecated and it's `GuildModeration` now.